# C++: How to duplicate a datatype?

Tags: c++, types

I want to use a datatype with a different name (create a duplicate of a type).
I don't want to use 'typedef' since that only creates a `#define`/macro like an alias.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef int AnInt;

struct Number
{
    int a;
};

template<typename T>
T var;

int main()
{
    var<int> = 5;
    var<AnInt> = 7; // does not what i want (this changes var<int>)
    var<Number>.a = 7;
    return 0;
}
```

This works exactly how I want it to work but I always need to access the type with the postfix `.a`.
Is there a way to avoid this?

### Edit:

The real-world application is that I have a `vec3` datatype and now I need to different datatypes `Position` and `Velocity` that are essentially a single `vec3`. They need to be different because I use an entity-component system that is based on templates.

Comment: What you're looking for is called a "strong typedef". It has to be emulated with a class in C++

Comment: Btw, this seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Either you accept implicit conversions to / from the base type, at which point they become (almost) interchangeable, or you have the `.member` everywhere. Pick one

Comment: Use a third party dimensioning/units library like boost::units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `typedef` simply creates an alias (not a macro though) for the type, you need to create a new type to represent its new identity. Since you want the access to the value to be as smooth as possible, you can define a new class and overload some operators:

```
template <class T>
class wrapper
{
    T value;
public:
    wrapper()
    {

    }

    wrapper(T &&obj) : value(std::move(obj))
    {

    }

    wrapper(const T &obj) : value(obj)
    {

    }

    operator T&()
    {
        return value;
    }

    operator const T&() const
    {
        return value;
    }

    T &operator*()
    {
        return value;
    }

    const T &operator*() const
    {
        return value;
    }

    const T &operator->() const
    {
        return value;
    }

    T &operator->()
    {
        return value;
    }
};
```

Add more operators, if necessary. Then, each new type shall inherit from this class like this:

```
struct new_int : public wrapper<int>
{
    new_int()
    {

    }

    new_int(int &&obj) : wrapper<int>(std::move(obj))
    {

    }

    new_int(const int &obj) : wrapper<int>(obj)
    {

    }
};
```

You can create a macro that helps with constructing these types:

```
#define new_type(name, base) struct name : public wrapper<base> { \
    name() {} \
    name(base &&obj) : wrapper<base>(std::move(obj)) {} \
    name(const base &obj) : wrapper<base>(obj) {} \
}
```

All these new types will be distinct from each other:

```
new_type(new_int1, int);
new_type(new_int2, int);

int main()
{
    var<int> = 12;
    var<wrapper<int>> = 13;
    var<new_int1> = 14;
    var<new_int2> = 15;
    std::cout << var<int> << std::endl;
    std::cout << var<wrapper<int>> << std::endl;
    std::cout << var<new_int1> << std::endl;
    std::cout << var<new_int2> << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: NB. The wrapper machinery is all just for making primitives heritable. You're still using exactly the same inheritance mechanism to make your final types.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to create a new, non-implicitly-convertible type with exactly the same layout as the original is inheritance:

```
struct Position: vec3 {};
struct Velocity: vec3 {};
```

Note that they're still implicitly convertible to `vec3d&`, just not to each other.

Comment: True, that takes more work, but the question does specifically mention `vec3` which I assumed to be a UDT.

Comment: I see. I didn't notice the edit, hence I assumed the solution had to be generic for all types.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure type safety try [foonathan/type_safe](https://github.com/foonathan/type_safe). This is a header-only library that provides mechanisms for opaque typedef emulation using standard C++:

> type_safe provides zero overhead abstractions that use the C++ type
>   system to prevent bugs.
>
> > Zero overhead abstractions here and in following mean abstractions that have no cost with optimizations enabled, but may lead to slightly
>
> lower runtime in debug mode, especially when assertions for this
>   library are enabled.
>
> The library features cannot really explained in the scope of this
>   readme, I highly suggest that you check out the [first](https://foonathan.net/blog/2016/10/11/type-safe.html) and [second](https://foonathan.net/blog/2016/10/19/strong-typedefs.html) blog
>   post and the examples.

If you only need to use strong typedefs for something that involves physics, have a look at [Boost.Units](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_units.html):

> The Boost.Units library is a C++ implementation of dimensional
>   analysis in a general and extensible manner, treating it as a generic
>   compile-time metaprogramming problem. With appropriate compiler
>   optimization, no runtime execution cost is introduced, facilitating
>   the use of this library to provide dimension checking in
>   performance-critical code. Support for units and quantities (defined
>   as a unit and associated value) for arbitrary unit system models and
>   arbitrary value types is provided, as is a fine-grained general
>   facility for unit conversions. Complete SI and CGS unit systems are
>   provided, along with systems for angles measured in degrees, radians,
>   gradians, and revolutions and systems for temperatures measured in
>   Kelvin, degrees Celsius and degrees Fahrenheit. The library
>   architecture has been designed with flexibility and extensibility in
>   mind; demonstrations of the ease of adding new units and unit
>   conversions are provided in the examples.

P.S. If you would like some code examples then let me know.